# How to specify queue in task decorator in celery

Tags: python, celery

I'm using celery in the following format:

```py
class SomeClass
    @task(queue="queue1")
    def method_to_run_thins_in_queuue_1(self, some_arguments):
        pass

    @task(queue="queue2")
    def method_to_run_thins_in_queuue_2(self, some_arguments):
        pass


# Usage:
SomeClass().method_to_run_things_in_queue_1.delay(some_arguments)
```

Every time I add a new queue, I need to add a new method with the name of the queue. I would like to know if there is a way for me to specify the queue name when calling to delay or as a parameter, to be able to make a generic function to trigger tasks in any celery queue. Something like:

```py
class SomeClass
    @task
    def method_to_run_thins_in_queuue_1(self, some_arguments):
        pass

    @task
    def method_to_run_thins_in_queuue_2(self, some_arguments):
        pass


# Usage:
SomeClass().method_to_run_things_in_queue_1.delay(queue="some queue", some_arguments)
```

Then I could decide programmatically where to send the task (from a dictionary that we have where based on some logic we decide where the task is run). I have taken a look at celery routers but they are not a good fit for our problem.

Comment: It is almost exacly like you want it, except that first come arguments, then queue="some-queue" (kwargs basically go after args). Also, no need to put tasks in a class. It is an unnecessary complication. Make them "free" functions, unless you really, really have to do it the way you described.